# How do I access a method outside of object while using a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, constructor, trello

I'm trying to get the member ID for a Trello account and then use that member ID in a constructor function to generate boards. My problem is that I can't access the member ID that I return outside of the object I created. How do I access the memberID outside of the TrellloConnect object?

Here is the code:

```
var TrelloConnect = {
init: function(config) {
    this.config = config;
    this.doAuthorize();
    this.updateLogStatus();
    this.bindLogIn();
    this.bindLogOut();
    this.whenAuthorized();
    this.getMemberID();
},
bindLogIn: function() {
    this.config.connectButton.click(function() {
        Trello.authorize({
            type: "redirect",
            success: this.doAuthorize,
            name: "WonderBoard",
            expiration: "never"
        });
    });
},
bindLogOut: function() {
    this.config.disconnectButton.click(function() {
        var self = TrelloConnect;
        Trello.deauthorize();
        self.updateLogStatus();
    });
},
doAuthorize: function() {
    var self = TrelloConnect;
    self.updateLogStatus();
},
updateLogStatus: function() {
    var isLoggedIn = Trello.authorized();
    this.config.loggedOutContainer.toggle(!isLoggedIn);
    this.config.loggedInContainer.toggle(isLoggedIn);
},
whenAuthorized: function() {
    Trello.authorize({
        interactive: false,
        success: TrelloConnect.doAuthorize
    });
},
getMemberID: function() {
    Trello.members.get("me", function(member) {
        console.log(member.id);
        return member.id;
    });
}
};

 TrelloConnect.init({
    connectButton: $('#connectLink'),
    disconnectButton: $('#disconnect'),
    loggedInContainer: $('#loggedin'),
    loggedOutContainer: $('#loggedout')
});

function Board(memberID) {
    console.log(memberID);
}

var board = new Board(TrelloConnect.getMemberID());
```

Comment: It looks like Trello.members.get is an asynchronous call. You will have to pass a success callback to getMemberID and any code you want to execute after the member is returned will go inside the callback.

Comment: I don't understand. How do you access it "inside the object"? You're not making it available anywhere.

Comment: How would I make it available? I think that's the part I'm having most trouble with? Do I need to initialize it somehow? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trello.members.get` is an asynchronous function (i.e. it takes a callback instead of returning a value); you'll need to use a callback if you want to do something with the data that it fetches.

If you change `getMemberID` to take a callback

```
...
getMemberID: function(callback) {
  Trello.members.get("me", function(member){
    callback(member.id);
  });     
}
...
```

... then you could do something like this:

```
TrelloConnect.getMemberId(function(id){
  new Board(id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That generally worked but now I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function trello-obj.js:47
(anonymous function) trello-obj.js:47
n jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
w jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
d jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4

Comment: I'm new to Javascript (and programming in general). Let me make sure I understand. "Trello.members.get" doesn't run at the same time of the rest of the code and I need it to run at a specific time. So when I do need to run it, I pass it an anonymous function that runs "Trello.members.get" and gives me access to a variable that I now use outside of that function. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, how would I access that new Board instance I created in the TrelloConnect.getMemberID call in the rest of the app?

Comment: The anonymous function does not call Trello.members.get, rather it defines what to do once Trello.members.get successfully returns the member. The issue isn't about what is inside the callback and what is outside of it. The issue is about WHEN you have the member and when you don't - the callback executes once you have the member.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do I have the member when request it using the callback? Because I'm asking for it?

Comment: The second argument to Trello.members.get is a function which will be the success handler/callback executed when the asynchronous call returns with a member. The success callback will always get passed the member, it's not because you are asking for it, but because that's what it's defined to do.

Comment: Do you know why I might be getting the Uncaught TypeError undefined is not an object? It points to the callback(member.id); line.

Comment: Yes. Because when you are calling this.getMemberID(); in the init function you are not passing a callback, so callback is undefined.

Comment: I see. I removed it from the init function altogether. I'm still not completely clear or when I need to run things in the init function and when it's not necessary. I guess when I run functions outside of the object I don't also need to run them in the init. At the risk of asking too much from you, would you mind helping me access the id variable outside of the call to TrelloConnect.getMemberID? The variable is scoped to that function. No matter what I do I can't seem to access it. (I've tried window and creating the var outside of the function). Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Trying to attach it to the global scope is going to make matters worse. The best way to use member.id is the way described in Daniel LeCheminant's answer above - by passing a callback to getMemberID. This way you can be certain it exists in the scope of your callback.

Comment: That would technically work but I am trying to figure out a way to have cleaner code and use objects instead of writing "messy" code. I have to run a series of .get functions to keep accessing deeper levels of content. Is using objects the right direction here? The code would look like this without objects: TrelloConnect.getMemberID(function(id) {
    Trello.get("members/" + id + "/boards", function(boards) {
        $.each(boards, function(index, board) {
            var boardID = board.id;
            Trello.get("boards/" + boardID + "/cards", function(cards) {...

Comment: Your code is going to have to look something like that because each Trello API call requires the previous one to return before it can go. Your callbacks don't have to be anonymous, so you could define them each as a var (or object property), but you would still end up with something like: getMemberID(getBoards, getCards);

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I'll get this working and try to improve from the old code as much as possible and use objects when I can.